# Link to multiple tags in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I tried doing `[tag:ruby+multi-threading]` in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080714/mri-ruby-combination-in-multicore#comment12907749_10080714), and got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby%2bmulti-threading , which looks on the right hand side like it's looking at a combination of [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [multi-threading](/questions/tagged/multi-threading) (in fact, pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> when you're in the search box gets you what you want), but gets zero results.

Ideally this should be fixed by allowing searches with multiple tags from comments, but otherwise, it should not give the misleading impression that it's searching by multiple tags.

Comment: Comments are rendered on-demand, so checking to see if the tag was valid seems too expensive for such a case (keep in mind that `+` is valid in tag names, so a `ruby+multi-threading` tag could technically exist). That said, the search page shouldn't lie about what it searched for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug here is that when multiple tags are linked, synonyms are not resolved to their master tag.

This url works fine:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby%2bmultithreading

But your example doesn't, because there is no [multi-threading](/questions/tagged/multi-threading) on Stack Overflow; it is a synonym of [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading).

We'll get this fixed.

Comment: fixed now ... to be deployed later

Comment: // drunk, fix later