# My combined tag search is suddenly broken

Tags: support, tag-search

I had a search (saved as a bookmark) that would search for posts that had various combinations of tags - `sql` and `server` separately, `ms` and `sql` separately, or `store` and `procedure` separately.

That link is stored as:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%20server%20or%20ms%20sql%20or%20store%20procedure
```

But suddenly, since a few days ago, this search gets "translated" into

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+server+or+microsoft+sql+or+store+procedure
```

and that of course is totally not the same search anymore......

- `sql+server` finds all entries with `sql-server` as well (that's the desired tag to use - but now I get thousands of hits instead of the hopefully few "bad" posts
- `microsoft+sql` is wrong because I was **specifically** searching for posts with a `ms` and `sql` tag - that's totally not the same thing anymore....

Why did this happen? What is the rationale behind changing this behavior?? Is there any way (with an additional hints or a different URL format) that I can "restore" my original search for bad posts ???

Comment: We pushed out a change where any [tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128755/link-to-multiple-tags-in-comments/128757#128757) would be negotiated to their master tag.  It also looks like [ms] was added as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/microsoft/synonyms) of [tag:microsoft], so there will be no more [ms] tagged questions.

Comment: Your bookmark was looking for improperly tagged questions?

Comment: @JarrodDixon: yes. I was hunting for those posts that have [sql] and [server] separately, or [store] and [procedure] etc. Those cases can't be handled by synonyms right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, your bookmark was looking for questions:

- tagged [sql] and [server]

  or
- tagged [ms] and [sql]

  or
- tagged [store] and [procedure]

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly - those can't be handled by synonyms. But since about last week, this logic in the URL has somehow changed - now my search is translated into the new URL I mentioned, and that URL finds way too many hits ... it's no longer filtering out the potential "problem cases" as before.

Comment: Except that now, [ms] can't appear on a question.  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft+sql) not look correct now?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand... now your bookmark *is* showing all those [microsoft]+[sql] questions, when before [ms] was hardly ever an issue (and one that needed fixing).  And because there's a synonym now, can you just remove it from that bookmark and use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+server+or+store+procedure) link?

Comment: Or this brings up a point that we currently have [69 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft+sql) tagged [microsoft] and [sql] which should probably be retagged!

Comment: Yes, that new URL of yours seems to work - thanks! And yes - those posts that have [microsoft] and [sql] should probably be retagged to have just [sql-server] (unless it's about SQL in MS-Access, of course!)